# How to refer js file in item display template

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, moment

I am trying to refer the moment.js file in display template for search content webpart. I have a display template with item template and control template. In the item template i am trying to add offset to the date for each item. Below is the way i have refer using `$includeScript`, but I am getting this error '`moment' is undefined` '. 
How to propery refer the js file in display template

Comment: How are you referencing moment.js? You say below is the way, but there's nothing below.

Answer (score 3):

If you only need the file available to this site collection, the easiest approach is to create a subfolder in your Master Page Gallery for your scripts. Then you can use a path relative to the site collection like this inside the body tag:

`$includeScript(this.url, "~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Search/MyNewFolder/moment.js")`

Change the subfolder from "search" to which ever folder you are using.

Comment: But even using this will not help since the item template will render first and and then the js file will load.

Comment: Have you tried adding it to the Control Template? Or do I not understand your issue. This always works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Install libraries globally with a User Custom Action

See: http://johnliu.net/blog/2015/12/the-safest-future-proof-way-to-brand-your-sharepoint-and-sharepoint-online

for a decent explanation

Then use the easier method to apply:
https://github.com/tavikukko/Chrome-SP-Editor

Comment: Will this cause the js file to load first, and then the item template where at it is using the js file refrence

Comment: Yes, UserCustomAction scriptlinks are loaded very very early on, add one, see the F12 Network tab. It is THE way to load all 3rd part libraries, available since SP2010, misunderstood by many. And that is also a reason why Microsoft killed it for Modern Experiences (where at the moment you can not do any branding at all, no CSS, no JS no nothing)

Answer (score 0):

[Moment.js's own documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/) states, that the following does the job:

```
<script src="moment.js"></script>
<script>
    moment().format();
</script>
```

Where `src="moment.js"` is the path to your m`oment.js`-file. You should add this snippet to either to a Content Editor Web Part, if you'll be needing the Moment.js's functions only in one location. If you will be needing it in multiple places, the file should be referred in the master page.